# Find all the invariant subspaces of T

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

T is a linear transformation, defined as the following: $T(p(x)) = xp(x)$, $T\colon R[X]\to R[X]$

Find all the invariant subspaces of $T$.

As I see it, only the trivial subspaces $0$, $R[X]$ are invariant because if I look at a arbitrary subspace $Rk[X]$ of polynomials with maximum degree of $k$, when I use the transformation on it I get polynomial in degree $k+1$ , so it is not in the subspace.

Am I missing something....?

Comment: Hint: What about the span of $x^7+1, T(x^7+1), T(T(x^7+1)),\ldots$? IOW, your argument only proves that there is a severe shortage of finite dimensional invariant subspace.

Comment: It's dimension is infinite?

Comment: and are there invariant subspaces with finite dimensions?

Comment: In a finite dimensional subspace there will be a maximum degree, and your argument takes over (dimension actually makes sense only, when $R$ is a field, but let's forget that for a moment). This is because the maximum degree of the basis elements is also the maximum degree of any linear combination. But there are several infinite dimensional invariant subspaces. Think: ideals.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an ideal please?

Comment: You haven't covered ideals in your class/book yet? Sorry, I should have realized that this is a possibility. In that case it is a bit taxing to describe all the invariant subspaces. The subspace in my first comment is the ideal generated by $x^7+1$. BTW, does $R$ stand for the real numbers here?

Comment: Yes, R is for real numbers. Sorry, I know what an ideal is. So you say that the ideal generated by x^7+1 is invariant subspace of T? interesting, I still can't see that because T only multiply it by x , and in ideal i can multiply it in any polynomial I want.

Comment: Yes. The ideal generated by $x^7+1$ consists of all the products $(x^7+1)q(x)$, where $q(x)\in \mathbf{R}[x]$ is an arbitrarty polynomial. Nothing stops you from replacing $x^7+1$ with a polynomial of your choice. Multiplying by, say, polynomial $x^2+x+1$ amounts to applying $T$ zero times, once, twice and taking the sum of the results. None of those operations will take you outside the invariant space.